# MERGE statement for SCD type 2 is creating duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below MERGE statement that I built to implement SCD type 2 on my SQL Server DB however if you look at the attached image, this sometimes inserts multiple duplicate rows which is incorrect - this should be one latest row per meterkey/meterserialnumber.

Is there anything obvious in the code I need to amend? It's weird because if I add a test row of data and run the merge, this works fine.. its just the occasional rows where it seems to be doing this.

[image]

```
             DECLARE @DateNow int = CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112))

          IF Object_id('tempdb..#meterkeysinsert') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE #meterkeysinsert;

          CREATE TABLE #meterkeysinsert
            (
               MeterKey int,
               change                    VARCHAR(10)
            );



          MERGE INTO [DIM].[MeterDetails] AS Target
          using dbo.test  AS Source
          ON Target.meterkey = source.meterkey
          and target.MeterSerialNumber = Source.MeterSerialNumber
          and target.islatest = 1

          WHEN matched THEN
            UPDATE SET Target.islatest = 0,
                       Target.todatekey = @Datenow

          WHEN NOT matched BY target THEN
            INSERT (    meterkey
      ,[MeterSerialNumber]
      ,[lguf]
      ,[electricityMetertype]
      ,[profileType]
      ,[timeSwitchCode]
      ,[lineLossFactorId]
      ,[standardSettlementConfiguration]
      ,[energisationStatus]
      ,[DateSpecifiedKey]
      ,[distributorId]
      ,[gspid]
      ,[FromDatekey]
      ,[ToDatekey]
      ,[IsLatest])
            VALUES (Source.meterkey
      ,Source.[MeterSerialNumber]
      ,Source.[lguf]
      ,Source.[electricityMetertype]
      ,Source.[profileType]
      ,Source.[timeSwitchCode]
      ,Source.[lineLossFactorId]
      ,Source.[standardSettlementConfiguration]
      ,Source.[energisationStatus]
      ,Source.[DateSpecifiedKey]
      ,Source.[distributorId]
      ,Source.[gspid]
      ,@Datenow
      ,NULL
      ,1              --IsRowCurrent
)
          output Source.meterkey,
                 $action
          INTO #meterkeysinsert;

          INSERT INTO [DIM].[MeterDetails]
                      (MeterKey
      ,[MeterSerialNumber]
      ,[lguf]
      ,[electricityMetertype]
      ,[profileType]
      ,[timeSwitchCode]
      ,[lineLossFactorId]
      ,[standardSettlementConfiguration]
      ,[energisationStatus]
      ,[DateSpecifiedKey]
      ,[distributorId]
      ,[gspid]
      ,[FromDateKey]
      ,[ToDateKey]
      ,[IsLatest])
          SELECT A.MeterKey
      ,[MeterSerialNumber]
      ,[lguf]
      ,[electricityMetertype]
      ,[profileType]
      ,[timeSwitchCode]
      ,[lineLossFactorId]
      ,[standardSettlementConfiguration]
      ,[energisationStatus]
      ,[DateSpecifiedKey]
      ,[distributorId]
      ,[gspid]
      ,@Datenow
      ,null
      ,1
          FROM  dbo.test a
                 INNER JOIN #meterkeysinsert CID
                         ON a.MeterKey = CID.Meterkey
                            AND CID.change = 'UPDATE'
`
```

Comment: Male it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Why don't know your data, just your query. As @jarlh suggested, can you simplify your question? Giving sample data and expected output is always welcomed.

Comment: Is the combination of `meterkey` and `meterserialnumber` definitely unique in your source data (ie, `dbo.test`)? If not, then the `when not matched by target` will be hit for all of the rows in the source, resulting in multiple inserts, resulting in multiple rows in `dim.meterdetails` all with the same value for `meterkey` and `meterserialnumber`, and all with `latest` set to 1. I also don't think the code is going to do what you expect: if you have a `latest` row, and then get another row that matches, all that will happen is the existing `latest` row will be set to 0. No insert will happen.